# Make Mac PKG Download File

Tags: macos, installation, pkg-file

On a Mac OSX PKG installer, is it possible to make it download an extra browser.plist settings file where I might have stored the user's browser brand and version (keyed by IP address)? See, advertisers love it when they get cookie continuity between someone who downloads a trial product and then connects to the cart to purchase it. If I can utilize the same browser, then the advertiser tracking cookie will be there and they can be paid a commission for the sale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A product like [the free Packages application from Stéphane Sudre](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) lets one make a PKG wizard-style setup pretty easily. One of the features of it is to have a [pre- or post-install script execute](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/documentation/Packages/en/Package_Settings_Customization.html#6), and this can be a Python or Bash script. From there, I can make it download a browser.plist file from the server. The server can read the user's IP address, read the database for browser and advertiser ID information, and inject that into the browser.plist file at the point of download. It can then delete the entry from the database (so that the database doesn't explode from the volume of traffic). The web server can then also remove any records older than x number of days as a failsafe so that the database doesn't explode from the volume of traffic.